# export array to csv Nodejs

Tags: node.js, csv, export-to-csv, node-modules

I'm trying to export an array of data to a CSV file in Nodejs. I'm using the NodeCSV module, but I just get errors every time I try to follow the examples and documentation. It prints a bunch of code and says stringifier has no method 'indexOf' when I try to use the stringifier and it says 'object is not a function' when I try

```
csv().from.array(results).to('/temp/users.csv')
```

It doesn't work if I take the () off csv either. Does anyone know how to do this or can point me to some good documentation?

Comment: try **.to(fs.createWriteStream('/temp/users.csv'))**

Answer (score -2):

Hope it help you more:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=testing.csv');
response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
});

csv().from(data).to(response)
```

})
.listen(3000);

Comment: I'm still getting 'object is not a function' on csv(). Do I have to store a value returned from csv() anywhere and then do a res.send or res.sendfile or is that taken care of by doing .to(response)?